# "Request a Web Hook" Form - Filters?

Tags: webhooks, evernote

The [Evernote documentation on web hooks](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/polling_notification.php#webhooks) states the following:

> If your service only cares about some notes, we can configure a filter on your API key. Notifications will only be sent when the note matches the filter. For example, the filter resource:image/* causes notifications to be sent anytime a note containing at least one image attachment is created or updated. The filter is configured on your API key, so it is the same for all users. The filter string supports our full search grammar.

This is great, except that the Webhook Request form doesn't have any input to specify a filter.

[image: Webhook Request Form]

1. How do we make a request with specific filters?
2. If we have multiple environments (dev, stage, prod), is it okay to make a request for the same API Consumer Key but for different URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response to my webhook request via email, at which point they asked if I needed the webhook to point to the sandbox or production environment. In my response, I also mentioned the filter I would like applied, and they proceeded to make the webhook the next day. Overall it took about a week and a half to get it setup.